# Comfortable way for debugging for-loops in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, loops, for-loop

How can I debug complicated for-loops in eclipse like in this code?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ListTraining {

    public void countOccurence() {
        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 3);
        Integer number = 3;     
        for (int i = numbers.indexOf(number), j = -1; i > j; j = i, i += numbers.subList(i + 1, numbers.size()).indexOf(number) + 1) {
            System.out.println("found number: " + number + " at position: " + i);           
        }       
    }

}
```

If I use "Step Over" I'm in the instruction block. If I use "Step Into" I'm inside methods like indexOf. How can I investigate the variables and calls in the loop header in a comfortable way?

Is it possible to jump in the single instructions of the loop like in the condition check or in the variable assignment?

Answer (score 1):

Pause the debugger at the for loop.  Highlight a section of code.  Right click it and select the "Inspect" option to see it's value (e.g., highlight `numbers.indexOf(number)` to see what the return value of that function is).

Comment: ctrl-shift-I if you're a keyboard nerd like me :D

Comment: If the debugger pauses in the variable initialization, I can't use this feature to investigate the value of the variables in the condition check.

Comment: For example, my debugger pauses in the variable increment step. After that, the condition check would be executed which I want to debug. How can I jump from the incrementation step, to the condition check step in the loop? Another breakpoint in the loop header for the different steps or some other mechanism would be nice.

Comment: `numbers` is initialized on the proceeding line.  Your statement is true, though doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 1):

use debug view's variables  components
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your for is running fine, i suggest using system.println(String the data incremented). To see the data in each loop. The console will show the content of the loop.

If your for is breaking at some point, i suggest using debug mode and putting a break point in the middle of the loop, the execution of the code will stop each time it reaches the breakpoint and you can look at all the variables in the for loop at that state.

Answer (score 0):

Split the head of the for loop into multiple lines

```
for (int i = numbers.indexOf(number), j = -1; 
            i > j; 
            j = i, i += numbers.subList(i + 1, numbers.size()).indexOf(number) + 1) {
        System.out.println("found number: " + number + " at position: " + i);           
    }
```